# Pausing main thread while waiting for DownloadFileAsync() with progress report

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, wait

As you can see in the middle of the code there is an ugly Thread blocking code that waits for the file to download and also enables progress report in the command line. I mean, it's still better than `Thread.Sleep()` or busy waiting, right? Anyway, I do know about `Wait/Pulse`, but I don't know how to apply that here.

Is a complete refactoring of my code to better suit that single async operation the cleanest solution? Can one override something in the `WebClient` class to utilize `Wait/Pulse` type of waiting?

Project and the function in question: [Github](https://github.com/friendlyanon/CFW2OFW-Helper/blob/master/CFW2OFW%20Helper/Program.cs#L596)

Relevant snippet:

```
static void GetPatch(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry, string part)
{
    string url = entry.Key,
        fname = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1),
        path = G.patchPath + "\\" + fname;
        bool exists = File.Exists(path);
    Console.Write(fname + " ... ");
    string message = "local";
    if ((exists && GetSHA1(path) != entry.Value) || !exists)
    {
        if (exists) File.Delete(path);
        G.wc.DownloadProgressChanged += Wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
        G.wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), part);
        while (G.wc.IsBusy)
        {
            // There must be a better way
            new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(200);
        }
        G.wc.DownloadProgressChanged -= Wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
        message = "done";
    }
    if (File.Exists(part)) File.Move(part, path);
    G.patchFNames.Enqueue(fname);
    Green(message);
}

private static void Wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int p = e.ProgressPercentage;
    p = p < 100 ? p : 99;
    Console.Write("{0:00}%\b\b\b", p);
}
```

Please bear with me, this is my very first project that I've written in C# and I'm an absolute novice at OOP and C#.

Comment: You definitely need to work on the code and clarity, but in general I think you are on a right way. You need 2 async processes, one for file download and the other for monitoring the progress. The second process has to be async too so that you don't block the UI, and you will have to update UI using the dispatcher.

Comment: Is it what you're looking for? https://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/09/14/how-to-use-net-webclient-synchronously-and-still-receive-progress-updates/

Comment: What about moving to async\await? There is `DownloadFileTaskAsync` which can be awaited, and that will throw away most of ugliness in this code.

Comment: Ah apologies, I should have mentioned that my compiler target is .NET 4.0, so no await/async for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me copy the code from the url in my comment:

```
public void DownloadFile(Uri uri, string desintaion)
{
  using(var wc = new WebClient())
  {
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += HandleDownloadProgress;
    wc.DownloadFileCOmpleted += HandleDownloadComplete;

    var syncObj = new Object();
    lock(syncObject)
    {
       wc.DownloadFileAsync(sourceUri, destination, syncObject);
       //This would block the thread until download completes
       Monitor.Wait(syncObject);
    }
  }

  //Do more stuff after download was complete
}

public void HandleDownloadComplete(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
{
   lock(e.UserState)
   {  
      //releases blocked thread
      Monitor.Pulse(e.UserState);
   }
}


public void HandleDownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs args)
{
  //Process progress updates here
}
```

Comment: Yes, perfect. I knew it that the userToken overload will be the key, but sadly MSDN isn't very descriptive/lacks examples.

Comment: this freezes  the ui thread. program never continues . at winform inside button_click

Answer (score 0):

Your high-level code should look like this

```
public async Task StartFileDownload()
{
    var downloadTask = StartDownload();
    var monitoringTask = StartMonitoringProgress();

    await Task.WhenAll(downloadTask, monitoringTask);
}
```

Your monitoring task should be checking download progress every N ms and update progress bar. Though you would not be able to do it directly as you are not on the UI process, you will have to "dispatch" UI update.

Comment: At quick glance, your code suggests that he's using `DownloadFileTaskAsync()` that returns `Task` when in reality he's using `DownloadFileAsync()` that uses [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Note regarding the above solution:

If the async download does not start (e.g. if you are inside of a WPF application), you may need to set the Thread SynchronizationContext to use a threadpool. If you do this, you then need to make sure to not change any UI elements from the callback.

```
SynchronizationContext orig = SynchronizationContext.Current;
// Use thread pool and not the SyncContext for WPF
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url), syncObject);
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(orig);
```